# Function that executes some code only once

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I'm attempting to write a function in which a part of it runs only once. I've got it to work so far but I'd ideally like it to work without adding a global variable. I've read about closures but either I don't understand them enough or I can't get one to work in my instance.

Bear in mind this is my first attempt at a project using vanilla javascript rather than jQuery. So no jQuery answers please.

Here is my code:

```
var videoLoaded = false;

function loadItem(element) {


    // If item is Video
    if( element.tagName == 'VIDEO' ) {

        if(videoLoaded != true) {

            // Load and play the video;
            element.setAttribute('preload', 'auto');
            element.play();
            videoLoaded = true;

            /* Push the dimensions through
             * to the videoFill function
             */
            element.addEventListener( 'loadedmetadata', function(e) {
                var dimensions = [element.videoWidth, element.videoHeight, document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.clientHeight]
                videoFill(element, dimensions);
            });
        }

        dimensions = [element.videoWidth, element.videoHeight, document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.clientHeight]
        videoFill(element, dimensions);

    }
}
```

I'd appreciate your help!

Comment: you do not need closures .. look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to use a closure (in this case, an immediately invoked function expression [IIFE]) to prevent creating a global variable:

```
var loadItem = (function() {  // This function will be immediately invoked
    var videoLoaded = false;  // This var only exists in our IIFE context, not global scope

    function loadItem(element) {

        if( element.tagName == 'VIDEO' ) {

            // loadItem() will still have access to videoLoaded even after the IIFE has completed and returned
            if(videoLoaded != true) {

                element.setAttribute('preload', 'auto');
                element.play();
                videoLoaded = true;

                element.addEventListener( 'loadedmetadata', function(e) {
                    var dimensions = [element.videoWidth, element.videoHeight, document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.clientHeight]
                    videoFill(element, dimensions);
                });
            }

            dimensions = [element.videoWidth, element.videoHeight, document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.clientHeight]
            videoFill(element, dimensions);

        }
    }

    return loadItem; // Return the function

}()); // Immediately invoke the IIFE closure
```

Comment: To clarify for the OP: this works because variable scope in JavaScript is function-based. (As explained in the comments here, the IIFE "closes over" its local `videoLoaded` variable. The function `loadItem` has access to the `videoLoaded` variable, however, even after the IIFE terminates and returns the `loadItem` function object.)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the function after it's first call

```
function loadItem(element) {
    // Code        

    // replace function with dummy function
    // next time when it will be called, will do nothing
    loadItem = function() {
         dimensions = [element.videoWidth, element.videoHeight, document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.clientHeight]
         videoFill(element, dimensions);
    };
}
```

Comment: `"part of it runs only once"`, not all of it... but a good idea!

Answer (score 1):

Use a helper like this

```
var once = function (fn) {
  var ran = false;
  return function () {
    if (!ran) {
      ran = true;
      return fn.apply(null, arguments);
    }
  };
};
```

Extract the code that you only want to be run once into a function

```
var runMeOnce = once(function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
});


var doSomething = function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        runMeOnce("you will only see this once");
    }, 1000);
};
```

Or you can take the OO approach and wrap it in a class

```
var VideoLoader = function (element) {
    this.loaded = false;
    this.el = element;
};

VideoLoader.prototype.fill = function (dimensions) {
    // ?
};

VideoLoader.prototype.load = function () {

    var element = this.el,
        _this   = this;

    // If item is Video
    if( element.tagName == 'VIDEO' ) {

        if(this.loaded != true) {

            // Load and play the video;
            element.setAttribute('preload', 'auto');
            element.play();
            this.loaded = true;

            /* Push the dimensions through
             * to the videoFill function
             */
            element.addEventListener( 'loadedmetadata', function(e) {
                var dimensions = [
                    element.videoWidth,
                    element.videoHeight,
                    document.documentElement.clientWidth,
                    document.documentElement.clientHeight
                ];
                _this.fill(dimensions);
            });
        }

        dimensions = [
            element.videoWidth,
            element.videoHeight,
            document.documentElement.clientWidth,
            document.documentElement.clientHeight
        ];
        this.fill(dimensions);

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a parameter of the function to store the global (this way you need no closures):

```
var f = function(){if(!f.b)alert('x');f.b = true;}
```

The above function will alert "x" only once.

Answer (score 0):

videoLoaded not necessarily needs to be global. You can use the module pattern:

```
var itemLoader = (function (videoFill) {
    'use strict';

    var videoLoaded = false;

    return {
        load: function (element) {
            var dimensions;

            if (element.tagName === 'VIDEO') {
                if (videoLoaded !== true) {
                    // Load and play the video;
                    element.setAttribute('preload', 'auto');
                    element.play();
                    videoLoaded = true;

                    /* Push the dimensions through
                     * to the videoFill function
                     */
                    element.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function (e) {
                        var dimensions = [element.videoWidth, element.videoHeight, document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.clientHeight]
                        videoFill(element, dimensions);
                    });
                }

                dimensions = [element.videoWidth, element.videoHeight, document.documentElement.clientWidth, document.documentElement.clientHeight]
                videoFill(element, dimensions);
            }
        }
    };
}(window.videoFill));

itemLoader.load(document.getElementById('your-video'));
```